# Team Foundation Server, Check out file without Workspace

Tags: vb.net, tfs

I have TFS url, and I have source File location, but I don’t have Workspace path. 
How to Check out file without workspace, or how to find workspace for some file?

I already make solution for checkout file in TFS, but in some cases I don’t have workspace path or name.

```
Dim TeamFoundationServerURL As String ="TFS url"

Dim TeamProjectCollection As TfsTeamProjectCollection

'Get project collectio
TeamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection( _
            New Uri(TeamFoundationServerURL), New UICredentialsProvider())

TeamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated()

Dim Workspace As Workspace

' get Version Control
Dim VersionControlServer As VersionControlServer
VersionControlServer = TeamProjectCollection.GetService(Of VersionControlServer)()

'location to check out files to:
Dim WorkspacePath As String = "__I dot have this path ___"

'find workspace
Workspace = VersionControlServer.GetWorkspace(WorkspacePath)

'Check out file
Workspace.PendEdit(SorceFilePath)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out without a workspace is not possible. So if you need to check out and don't have any workspace information - you should create a wokspace on demand.
There's also an option to get file downloaded without a workspace VersionControlServer.DownloadFile. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.downloadfile(v=vs.80).aspx   for details. It will not be checked out though (like "view" console command).

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do this with my autobuild.  I had it checking out a version file and then checking it back in (after updating it).  Since this was the build machine I did not have a work space mappings that I could guarantee.

I ended up just checking to see if the file I needed was mapped.  If it was not then I would map it.

I know that is not the solution you were looking for, but I thought I would throw it out there for you to consider.

Here is my code that does the checking out and checking in:

```
private Version GetVersionFromTFS(Workspace currentWorkspace, string versionFileLocation, string versionFileName, out string localVersionPath)
{
    // Make sure we have a map to the version file
    if (!currentWorkspace.IsServerPathMapped(versionFileLocation))
    {
        // Map the version file to somewhere.
        currentWorkspace.Map(versionFileLocation, @"C:\temp\BuildVersions" + Guid.NewGuid());
    }

    // Make sure we have the latest from source control.
    GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(new ItemSpec(versionFileLocation + versionFileName,RecursionType.None), VersionSpec.Latest);
    currentWorkspace.Get(getRequest, GetOptions.Overwrite);           

    localVersionPath = currentWorkspace.GetLocalItemForServerItem(versionFileLocation + versionFileName);

    string oldVersion = "1.0.0.0";
    if (File.Exists(localVersionPath))              
        oldVersion = File.ReadAllText(localVersionPath);

    return new Version(oldVersion);
}

private void UpdateVersionBackToTFS(Workspace currentWorkspace, string versionFileLocation, string versionFileName, Version newVersion, String localVersionPath)
{
    File.WriteAllText(localVersionPath, newVersion.ToString()); 

    WorkspaceCheckInParameters parameters = new WorkspaceCheckInParameters(new[] {new ItemSpec(versionFileLocation + versionFileName, RecursionType.None)}, "***NO_CI*** - Updating Version" );

    currentWorkspace.CheckIn(parameters);

}
```